# Slick Object Movement

Tags: java, slick2d

I am making a game where the the user is supposed to dodge objects. However, I cant figure out how to make an obstacle move around the screen randomly as the user is moving. Below is the code I have used

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Play extends BasicGameState{
    int spriteXPos = 0;
    int spriteYPos = 422;
    int bulletXPos = 690;
    int bulletYPos = 400;
public Play (int state) {

}

public void init(GameContainer gameContainer, StateBasedGame stateBasedGame) 
throws SlickException {

}

public void render(GameContainer gameContainer, StateBasedGame 
stateBasedGame, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    Image castle = new Image("res/rsz_1background02.png");
    Image spriteWalking = new Image("res/marioWalking.png");
    Image spriteJumping = new Image("res/marioJumping.png");
    Image bullet = new Image("res/bullet.png");

    g.drawImage(castle, 0, 0);
    g.drawImage(spriteWalking, spriteXPos, spriteYPos);
    g.drawImage(bullet, bulletXPos, bulletYPos);
    g.drawString("X-Coordinate: " + spriteXPos + "\nY-Coordinate: " +      
          spriteYPos, 620, 30);
}

public void update(GameContainer gameContainer, StateBasedGame 
stateBasedGame, int delta) throws SlickException {
    Input input = gameContainer.getInput();

    if (input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_UP)) {
        spriteYPos -= 2;
        if (spriteYPos < 222)
            spriteYPos += 2;
    } else if (input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_DOWN)) {
        spriteYPos += 2;
        if (spriteYPos > 422)
            spriteYPos -= 2;
    } else if (input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_LEFT)) {
        spriteXPos -= 2;
        if (spriteXPos < 0)
            spriteXPos += 2;
    } else if (input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
        spriteXPos += 2;
        if (spriteXPos > 496)
            spriteXPos -= 2;
    }
}

public int getID() {
    return 1;
}

}
```

Comment: By Moving I was talking about the bullet object/image

Answer (score 0):

1. Be careful when you are moving (changing x & y) entities in your *update* method, because it is not called every second. It is called each **frame**, and the time between each frame is not fixed (depending on many things, such as your computer).

   So you can't just do "spriteYPos -= 2", because sometimes it will be called 10 times in one second, and sometimes 11 or 12 ; making your animation jerky.
2. How to face this problem? Here comes the **delta** parameter of your *update* method. delta corresponds to the number of milliseconds between each frame. So basically you just have to use it with your updates of X and Y.

   *e.g.* spriteYPos -= 0.2 * delta;
3. Finally, to move an obstacle randomly or not on the screen, you have to increase/decrease the X/Y of your obstacle in the update method, by using the delta parameter.

   Something like this:

   ```
   public void update(GameContainer gameContainer, StateBasedGame stateBasedGame, int delta) throws SlickException {
       [...]
       bulletXPos += 0.1 * delta;
       bulletYPos += 0.1 * delta;
   }
   ```

You can find more information about delta (how it works, and how to use it) here: [LWJGL Basic Timing](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_4_%28Timing%29)